# Is there a way to get event every time that Iptables rules/chains are modified?

Tags: linux, iptables

I wish to know if there is any way to subscribe to event which accrue every time that iptables rule/chain is modified/added/deleted?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use auditd and set a rule to catch actions such as modify/read/write.

The link[1] could be useful:

[1] [https://www.gotothings.com/linux/auditing-change-settings-iptables.htm#:~:text=Auditd%2C%20the%20SELinux,that%20later%20on](https://www.gotothings.com/linux/auditing-change-settings-iptables.htm#:%7E:text=Auditd%2C%20the%20SELinux,that%20later%20on).

If it works for you, this link[2] can help you to set your rules and work with auditd

[2] [https://www.tecmint.com/linux-system-auditing-with-auditd-tool-on-centos-rhel/#:~:text=Examples%20of%20Auditd%20System%20Call%20Rules&text=action%20%E2%80%93%20has%20two%20possible%20values,GID%20etc%20to%20modify%20rule](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-system-auditing-with-auditd-tool-on-centos-rhel/#:%7E:text=Examples%20of%20Auditd%20System%20Call%20Rules&text=action%20%E2%80%93%20has%20two%20possible%20values,GID%20etc%20to%20modify%20rule).